# On Vector / Matrix / Linear algebra libraries performance (c++)

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, linear-algebra, benchmarking

I am writing a machine learning library from scratch (on CPU). It involves a lot of operations on vectors of floats. My goal is to build a very efficient and fast library. To do so, I identified a list of core operations on vectors I need: element wise addition, element wise multiplication, dot product, element wise sqrt/pow/exp. The performance of my machine learning library is heavily dependant of the performance of these operations.

I am aware the performance of vector operations on float require SIMD, instruction pipelining, cache lines optimizations and the removal of float IEEE standard checks (meaning removing denormal values, NaN / 0+ / 0- checking etc.).

There are numerous c++ libraries that have the vectors core operations I need and they often leverage BLAS (or openBLAS) for SIMD operations. I used Armadillo for quite some time, without so much benchmarking and comparison with other libraries. But after some profiling on my program I discovered that the program spend negligible time in the openblas library. I have then decided to really benchmark the performance of different library implementations and to compare with a naïve implementation based on the `std::vector`:

---

Vector size - 10 000 float, number of operations - 1 000 000

**Element wise addition**

```
std::vector - 2s:477ms:183μs:102ns
armadillo - 2s:452ms:828μs:409ns
blaze - 2s:404ms:917μs:747ns
VCL(SSE2) - 1s:957ms:42μs:608ns
```

**Element wise multiplication**

```
std::vector - 2s:438ms:7μs:792ns
armadillo - 2s:433ms:195μs:322ns
blaze - 2s:415ms:86μs:600ns
VCL(SSE2) - 1s:927ms:301μs:214ns
```

**Scalar / dot / inner product**

```
std::vector - 2s:681ms:335μs:990ns
armadillo - 2s:600ms:441μs:415ns
blaze - 2s:289ms:95μs:894ns
VCL(SSE2) - 3s:485ms:100μs:644ns
```

**List of compared libraries**

Armadillo(+openBLAS): http://arma.sourceforge.net/

Blaze(+openBLAS): https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib/blaze

VCL: http://www.agner.org/optimize/

---

Surprisingly, the naïve implementation is as fast as Armadillo and Blaze (the difference is quite negligible). The VCL is ~23% faster than the other implementations for element wise addition and multiplication. It is essentially due to the PGO (Profile Guided Optimizations) of GCC, without it, it has the same performance.

So, my questions are:

- It seems that the compiler already optimize naïve implementations with SIMD and instruction pipelining. Does a linear algebra library can really do better on these core operations ? (I can update the post with other library benchmarks if needed).
- Is my benchmarking method adapted to the task ? (the code is following)

Benchmark code - `vec-bench.cpp`:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <blaze/Math.h>
#include <vcl/vectorclass.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// -----------------------BENCHMARK-FUNCTIONS---------------------------
typedef std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400>> days;

#define BENCHMARK_START \
{   \
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

#define BENCHMARK_END(name, itCount) \
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); \
    std::cout << "Benchmark for " << name << ":\n  " << hreadableUnit(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1)) \
                        << " total\n  " << hreadableUnit(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1) / itCount) \
                        << " average per iteration\n\n"; \
}

std::string hreadableUnit(std::chrono::nanoseconds ns) {
  auto d = std::chrono::duration_cast<days>(ns);
  ns -= d;
  auto h = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(ns);
  ns -= h;
  auto m = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(ns);
  ns -= m;
  auto s = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(ns);
  ns -= s;
  auto millis = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(ns);
  ns -= millis;
  auto micros = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(ns);
  ns -= micros;

  std::stringstream ss;
  bool evenZero = false;
  if (d.count() || evenZero) {
    ss << d.count() << "d:";
    evenZero = true;
  }
  if (h.count() || evenZero) {
    ss << h.count() << "h:";
    evenZero = true;
  }
  if (m.count() || evenZero) {
    ss << m.count() << "m:";
    evenZero = true;
  }
  if (s.count() || evenZero) {
    ss << s.count() << "s:";
    evenZero = true;
  }
  if (millis.count() || evenZero) {
    ss << millis.count() << "ms:";
    evenZero = true;
  }
  if (micros.count() || evenZero) {
    ss << micros.count() << "μs:";
    evenZero = true;
  }
  if (ns.count() || evenZero) {
    ss << ns.count() << "ns";
    evenZero = true;
  }

  if (!evenZero)
    ss << "N/A";

  return ss.str();
}


// ----------------------ACTUAL-PROCESSING------------------------------
int main() {
    /* vector size, number of iterations */
    const unsigned int vSize = 10000, itCount = 1000000;
    float sum;

    /* std */
    std::vector<float> v(vSize), u(vSize);

    /* armadillo */
    arma::fvec av(vSize, arma::fill::randu), au(vSize, arma::fill::randu);
    unsigned int i, j;

    /* blaze */
    blaze::StaticVector<float, vSize, blaze::columnVector> bv, bu;

    /* SSE2 VCL (my processor cannot do better than SSE2) */
    unsigned int sse2VSize = vSize / 4, reminder = vSize % 4; 

    std::vector<Vec4f> vclv(sse2VSize), vclu(sse2VSize);
    std::vector<float> vclrv(reminder), vclru(reminder); /* reminder */

    std::cout << "----------------ELEMENT-WISE-ADDITION-----------------\n";
    BENCHMARK_START
        for (i = 0; i < itCount; ++i)
            for (j = 0; j < vSize; ++j)
                v[j] += u[j];
    BENCHMARK_END("standard vector addition", itCount)

    BENCHMARK_START
        for (i = 0; i < itCount; ++i)
            av += au;
    BENCHMARK_END("armadillo vector addition", itCount)

    BENCHMARK_START
        for (i = 0; i < itCount; ++i)
            bv += bu;
    BENCHMARK_END("blaze vector addition", itCount)

    BENCHMARK_START
        for (i = 0; i < itCount; ++i)
            for (j = 0; j < sse2VSize; ++j)
                vclv[j] += vclu[j];

        if (reminder) {
            for (i = 0; i < itCount; ++i)
                for (j = 0; j < reminder; ++j)
                    vclrv[j] += vclru[j];
        }
    BENCHMARK_END("VCL(SSE2 - 4floats) vector addition", itCount)


    std::cout << "-------------ELEMENT-WISE-MULTIPLICATION--------------\n";
    BENCHMARK_START
        for (i = 0; i < itCount; ++i)
            for (j = 0; j < vSize; ++j)
                v[j] *= u[j];
    BENCHMARK_END("standard vector element wise multiplication", itCount)

    BENCHMARK_START
        for (i = 0; i < itCount; ++i)
            av %= au;
    BENCHMARK_END("armadillo vector element wise multiplication", itCount)

    BENCHMARK_START
        for (i = 0; i < itCount; ++i)
            bv *= bu;
    BENCHMARK_END("blaze vector element wise multiplication", itCount)

    BENCHMARK_START
        for (i = 0; i < itCount; ++i)
            for (j = 0; j < sse2VSize; ++j)
                vclv[j] *= vclu[j];

        if (reminder) {
            for (i = 0; i < itCount; ++i)
                for (j = 0; j < reminder; ++j)
                    vclrv[j] *= vclru[j];
        }
    BENCHMARK_END("VCL(SSE2 - 4floats) element wise multiplication", itCount)


    std::cout << "------------SCALAR / DOT / INNER PRODUCT-------------\n";
    BENCHMARK_START
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < itCount; ++i)
            for (j = 0; j < vSize; ++j)
                sum += (v[j] * u[j]);

        /* force the compiler to not remove 
         * the calculation by using the 'sum' 
         * variable */
        std::cout << sum << "\n";
    BENCHMARK_END("standard vector scalar / dot / inner product", itCount)

    BENCHMARK_START
        auto aut = au.t(); /* transposed */
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < itCount; ++i)
            sum += as_scalar(av * aut);
        std::cout << sum << "\n";
    BENCHMARK_END("armadillo vector scalar / dot / inner product", itCount)

    BENCHMARK_START
        blaze::StaticVector<float, vSize, blaze::rowVector> but = blaze::trans(bu); /* transposed */
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < itCount; ++i)
            sum += blaze::dotu(bv, but);
        std::cout << sum << "\n";
    BENCHMARK_END("blaze vector scalar / dot / inner product", itCount)

    BENCHMARK_START
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < itCount; ++i)
            for (j = 0; j < sse2VSize; ++j)
                sum += horizontal_add((vclv[j] * vclu[j]));

        if (reminder) {
            for (i = 0; i < itCount; ++i)
                for (j = 0; j < reminder; ++j)
                    sum += (vclrv[j] * vclru[j]);
        }
        std::cout << sum << "\n";
    BENCHMARK_END("VCL(SSE2 - 4floats) scalar / dot / inner product", itCount)

    return 0;
}
```

Benchmark compilation:

```
g++ -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -DARMA_USE_BLAS -DNDEBUG -DARMA_NO_DEBUG -march=native -O3 -ffast-math -std=c++14 -o vec-bench vec-bench.cpp -lopenblas -fprofile-use
```

**Edit**

Oprofile data:

**Element wise addition**

```
armadillo: 99.6462% -> void arma::arrayops::inplace_plus_base<float>(float*, float const*, unsigned long long)
blaze: 99.7094% -> main (meaning all blaze functions are inlined and it never go into openblas)
```

**Element wise multiplication**

```
armadillo: 99.6596% -> void arma::arrayops::inplace_mul_base<float>(float*, float const*, unsigned long long)
blaze: 99.6650% -> main (same as above)
```

**Scalar product**

```
armadillo: 84.3580% -> /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.18.so
blaze: 84.8001% -> /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.18.so
```

So armadillo and blaze use BLAS only for the dot product.

Comment: You'd expect some variability from sample run to sample run, so benchmarking only a single run doesn't provide much insight. Secondly you are essentially benchmarking BLAS/openBLAS, not Armadillo or Blaze -- both should defer to BLAS for the actual computation. Useful if you want to know/profile overheads but not if you want to compare raw linear algebra perf with a naïve implementation. Note: Armadillo also allows you to swap in other backends, may be interesting to look at. Thirdly: have you looked into opportunity for parallelisation?

Comment: The longer time for dot product suggests you didn't use enough accumulators - dot product has an annoying dependency structure so you need lots of accumulators to hide the FMA latency (or, without FMA, addition latency). Element wise operations are hard to improve, you could experiment with memory tricks (streaming, prefetching, TLB priming, etc)

Comment: @user268396 I took several measures, but it does not change the conclusions. For your second observation, I added oprofile data that show that armadillo and blaze use BLAS only for dot product. I'll try to swap with ATLAS for the back-end for the dot product. For your third point, I use parallelisation whenever it is possible for the bottlenecks at the algorithmic level in my library.

Comment: @harold I tried the dot product with 4 accumulators, but it does not help. The vectors have a size of 10k, I think that's the reason. I will try the Block algorithm for abusing the cache lines size (but on my lib, it would not help on this toy example). Thx for the ideas.

Comment: 10k isn't that big, should easily fit in LLC. 4 accumulators is still not a lot, eg for Haswell you need 10 (FMA latency is 5, throughput is 2/cycle)

Comment: `sum += horizontal_add((vclv[j] * vclu[j]))` : **never do horizontal sum *inside* the inner loop.**  This is your bottleneck!  Use *vector* accumulators.  See [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45113527) for more about using optimizing a dot-product (including with multiple accumulators for FMA).